# Unable to to signout from firebase authentication using redux. User session is still there

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-native-router-flux

**Summary:**

I am using firebase for authentication. I am trying to singout using the firebase signout() method. After signout user is navigating to the login scene using Actions.auth(). [auth is my login form scene name]

**Issue:,**

 After using sign out it properly navigates to the login screen. 
But when I login again it shows me blank screen. And when I do any activity e.g. touch the screen in the blank space then the data appears again.

I think I am doing something wrong [obviously haha] or I am missing some fundamentals.

Looking for help.

All I need user to logout and navigate to the login screen.

**1. I created action in types.js**

`export const LOG_OUT_USER = 'log_out_user';`

**2. I created an action in AuthActions.js and imported on top  'LOG_OUT_USER' and added the code as below**

```
 export const logOutUser = () => dispatch => {
  firebase.auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Sign-out successful');
      dispatch({ type: LOG_OUT_USER });
      Actions.auth();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

**3. in AuthReducer.js  I imported the    'LOG_OUT_USER' and added the case as below**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  user: null,
  error: '',
  loading: false
 };


 case LOG_OUT_USER:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
```

**4. I added a logout button in Employee List.**

```
//imported the action
import { employeesFetch, logOutUser } from '../actions';

//added function after 'componentWillReceiveProps' function
onButtonPressLogout() {
    console.log('logout');
    this.props.logOutUser();
  }



//added card section with logout button
<CardSection>
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPressLogout.bind(this)}>
                Log Out
            </Button>
</CardSection>

//exported at the bottom 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeesFetch, logOutUser })(EmployeeList);
```

In case you want to look at repo: https://github.com/hemantc09/react-native-Manager-Employee-App

Just download and run command :  -  `react-native run-ios`

Ouput: 
First time login:

[image]

After logout and then re-login: shows . blank screen. 
I see in the console the user data is still printing even after logout. 
What I a missing here.

[image]

If you want to take look using testflight let me know. I will send you invite.

Comment: I tried the to get the response but it gives me the undefined. Not sure whats missing.

```export const logOutUser = () => dispatch => {
  firebase.auth()
    .signOut()
    .then((response) => {

        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response);


      dispatch({ type: LOG_OUT_USER });
      Actions.auth();
      console.log('Sign-out successful');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};```

Comment: Are you sure Firebase is actually logging you out?

Comment: That’s the things . It’s confusing me and I’m missing  something. I tried the response and it give me undefined